# Unable to dump a folder from 100Gb SVN repo

Tags: performance, svn, directory, dump

I need to extract a folder from my SVN repository and preserve its history. So I decided to use **svnadmin dump** command. My SVN repo is huge - 100 Gb and 120k of revisions. Im using this command:

```
svnadmin dump D:\Repositories\SvnRepository -r 107968 | svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs include src/build/BambooScripts | "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a d:\temp\backup.7z -si dump.svn
```

so I pointed only one revision, applied a filter with my folder path and zipped an output. Now this command is already run for 4 hours. And I dont see any progress or messages in a console. So how can I speed up this process or at least estimate remaining time? Or may be there is another better way to extract folder from repository with the history?

Answer (score 0):

*svnadmin dump* dumps all paths in your repository. Depending on the size of your repository this can take a very long time even for a single revision (SVN has to dump **everything** that existed at that given revision). SVN will not give you any progress-updates during the dump of a single revision. You can however take a look at the dumpfile (be careful not to use an editor which automatically converts end-of-line characters), but this will probably be impractical if not impossible to open due to the size of the dumpfile.

If you just need a single folder from your repository you may want to use *svnrdump*:

> You can even dump a subtree of the repository — something that
>   svnadmin dump cannot do.

(http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)

In your case:

```
svnrdump dump file:///D:/Repositories/SvnRepository/SomeFolder -r start:end > dumpfile
```

There is no "--drop-empty-revs" option for svnrdump but you can get rid of empty revisions with svndumpfilter:

```
svndumpfilter --drop-all-empty-revs include / < dumpfile > filtered_dumpfile
```